# What happens to list when it is modified in recursive function arguments

Tags: python, backtracking, n-queens

This is a solution for the n-queen question. In recursion calls, it passes modified lists. My question is for each recursion call, does it create three new lists: queens, xy_dif, xy_sum and keep them in the call stack? Or there are only those three lists, each recursive call just modified them in place? If that is the case, I don't understand how it solves the problem like below:

DFS([],[],[]) calls DFS([0], [0], [0]), then DFS([0], [0], [0]) calls DFS([0,2],[0,-1],[0,3]), it didn't pass the if condition so it returns.

Then the for loop continue, q=3, my question is why is DFS([0,3],[0,-2],[0,4]) the next call instead of DFS([0,2,3],[0,-1,-2],[0,3,4])?

How was those three lists reverted back to the state of original states after call DFS([0], [0], [0])?

```
def solveNQueens(self, n):
    def DFS(queens, xy_dif, xy_sum):
        print('call function DFS({},{},{})'.format(queens, xy_dif, xy_sum))
        p = len(queens)
        print('updated row p is ', p)
        if p==n:
            result.append(queens)
            print('p==n, result is ', result)
            return None
        for q in range(n):
            print('loop starts, q is ', q)
            if q not in queens and p-q not in xy_dif and p+q not in xy_sum: 
                DFS(queens+[q], xy_dif+[p-q], xy_sum+[p+q])  
    result = []
    DFS([],[],[])
    return [ ["."*i + "Q" + "."*(n-i-1) for i in sol] for sol in result]
```

Comment: `queens+[q]`, and your other two parameters to the recursive call, are constructing new lists.  They refer to the same items as the original lists (which would be relevant if the items were mutable, such as sub-lists), but are not otherwise connected to the original lists.

Comment: Yes, and this really has nothing to do with recursion, it has to do with the semantics of the concatenation operator, `+` with list objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some "standard" recursion tracking, and you can see the results easily.  The `id` function is your friend in this case, showing whether a particular parameter refers to the same entity.

As you can see in the output below, each parameter has a unique id: it's an independent object.  This is because you have *not* passed the parameters of one call to the next.  Rather, you've created a temporary variable on the stack.  If you simply pass through `queens`, for example, then that list reference is shared by all calls.

On the other hand, `queens+[q]` is *not* `queens`; rather, it is a new list expression: a temporary variable on the stack, with a separate value.

If you wished to share the structures, you would first alter `queens`, and then pass that altered version to the next level:

```
queens.append(q)
DFS(queens, xy_dif+[p-q], xy_sum+[p+q])
```

In this usage, `xy_diff` and `xy_sum` are still independent variables on each call, b ut `queens` is shared.

Your code with recursion instrumentation:

```
indent = ""

def DFS(queens, xy_dif, xy_sum):
    global indent
    print(indent, "ENTER DFS", queens, xy_dif, xy_sum)
    print(indent, "parameter IDs:", id(queens), id(xy_dif), id(xy_sum))
    indent += "  "

    print('call function DFS({},{},{})'.format(queens, xy_dif, xy_sum))
    p = len(queens)
    print('updated row p is ', p)

    if p==n:
        result.append(queens)
        print('p==n, result is ', result)
        indent = indent[2:]
        return None

    for q in range(n):
        print('loop starts, q is ', q)
        if q not in queens and p-q not in xy_dif and p+q not in xy_sum: 
            DFS(queens+[q], xy_dif+[p-q], xy_sum+[p+q])  

    result = []
    DFS([],[],[])
    send_back = [ ["."*i + "Q" + "."*(n-i-1) for i in sol] for sol in result]

    print(indent, "LEAVE DFS", queens, xy_dif, xy_sum)
    indent = indent[2:]
    return send_back
```

Start of output:

```
 ENTER DFS [] [] []
 parameter IDs: 1813255818376 1813255818888 1813255819016
call function DFS([],[],[])
updated row p is  0
loop starts, q is  0
   ENTER DFS [0] [0] [0]
   parameter IDs: 1813255827784 1813258276680 1813255818760
call function DFS([0],[0],[0])
updated row p is  1
loop starts, q is  0
loop starts, q is  1
loop starts, q is  2
     ENTER DFS [0, 2] [0, -1] [0, 3]
     parameter IDs: 1813255817480 1813255817352 1813255817928
call function DFS([0, 2],[0, -1],[0, 3])
updated row p is  2
loop starts, q is  0
loop starts, q is  1
loop starts, q is  2
loop starts, q is  3
       ENTER DFS [] [] []
       parameter IDs: 1813255817864 1813255817736 1813255816712
call function DFS([],[],[])
updated row p is  0
loop starts, q is  0
         ENTER DFS [0] [0] [0]
         parameter IDs: 1813255816392 1813255816264 1813255816136
call function DFS([0],[0],[0])
...
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your time. I will definitely save this as a template for future.